# how to handle useEffect with render props in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to use a render props function with hooks but I am not entirely sure if this is possible.

I have a `FetcherComponent` that takes a renderprop but I want to use a `setState` from

```
export const HierarchyGraph: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [rootNode, setRootNode] = useState<HierarchyNode<GraphicalNode> | null>(null);

  return (
    <Fetcher
      url="/hierarchy"
      initialData={{}}
      render={({ data }: { data: TreeData }) => {
          // this will cause infinite recursion
          setRootNode(getHierarchy(data));
```

Should I not use render props in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a render prop but you have to branch inside the render function of `HierarchyGraph` to detect whether or not you have to make the call. Otherwise the request is triggered multiple times. Here is a quick example:

```
const HierarchyGraph = () => {
  const [rootNode, setRootNode] = useState(null);

  if (!rootNode) {
    return (
      <Fetcher
        url="/hierarchy"
        initialData={{}}
        render={({ data }) => {
          setRootNode(getHierarchy(data));
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  return <div>render the data related to rootNode</div>;
};
```

An alternative solution is to inline the call inside the render function and perform the operation on each render. It depends on the use case but if the operation is cheap it might be simpler. The last alternative is to leverage [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) rather than the `Fetcher` component. Its usage would be more suited than the render prop pattern since you can explicitly trigger the call to the API only once.

Comment: thank you for the answer, the reason i want to use the fetcher is because it renders loading an error markup if appropriate.  is it possible to do this with hooks

Comment: With the example I gave you it should be possible to render the `Fetcher` only when it's require, but fall back on the "default" render once the data is available.

Answer (score 0):

it causes infinite recursion because of `setRootNode` causing re-render of HierarchyGraph and this again triggers `setRootNode`. You need to find a way to stop this state updates when it's not necessary e.g:

```
export const HierarchyGraph = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  return (
    <Fetcher
      url="/hierarchy"
      initialData={data}
      render={({ data: newData }) => {
          if(data !== newData) { 
            setData(newData);
          }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right approach. This implementation will perform two calls: one on the first render plus another one once the `setRootNode` call is triggered.